# How to pass the billing name in stripe payment card mount?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to pass the billing name on my stripe payment (like below)

```
    var cardCvcElement = elements.create('billingName', {
      style: style,
      placeholder: 'Name on card',
    });
    cardCvcElement.mount('#card-user-name');
```

but it is giving me the following error  `A valid Element name must be provided. Valid Elements are: card, cardNumber, cardExpiry, cardCvc, postalCode, paymentRequestButton, iban, idealBank, p24Bank, auBankAccount, fpxBank, affirmMessage, afterpayClearpayMessage; you passed: billingName.`

I am not sure how to send the billing name as part of the payment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an Element, you can create either a *Payment Element* (*new* component) or *Card Element* (*old* component).

It looks like you have created a Card Element, hence it's expecting a "valid" element name of `card, cardNumber, cardExpiry, cardCvc, postalCode, paymentRequestButton, iban, idealBank, p24Bank, auBankAccount, fpxBank, affirmMessage, afterpayClearpayMessage`. See [Stripe JS Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=card#elements_create-type).

[image]

I suggest taking a step back and fixing the correct syntax for this call first, before thinking of how to send the billing name. Pretty much you would want Payment Element instead, and as other answer pointed out, you will need to pass the billing Details in the defaultValues under [options](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_payment_element#payment_element_create-options-defaultValues-billingDetails-name).

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a [payment element](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/payment_element), you need to pass the billing details in the [defaultValues](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_payment_element#payment_element_create-options-defaultValues) object  under the [options](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_payment_element#payment_element_create-options) object.

Comment: was it working for you? I tried to provide a country with it but it is still showing the country from my IP address